# Using GIT from filezilla

Tags: git, filezilla

The changes which are done in GIT project folders thru filezilla whether in hooks folder or any folder in .git directory need to be committed or not?
Also, I am doing some changes in hooks folder opened in filezilla and have saved it there but did not do any commits & while opening git bash I donot see any of these changes so is it because I did not do any commit or its any other reason?

Comment: if you edit the remote file in filezilla (and save your file) (and filezilla asks you if you want to overwrite the remote file with your local file AND you say yes) then when you ssh into your remote server's filesystem and change to the directory 'hook' and do 'git status', you should see the file that you changed as being edited. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insofar as 'being live' if you are talking about a website, then the answer is 'no'.  You do not to 'commit' changes with 'git' before the files are live.

the second you overwrite your remote file with your local copy from filezilla, the html, or js or whatever you're editing will be live immediately without typing any 'git' commands

However, if you do not do

```
git -A .
git commit
git push
```

then you will not have an all encompassing 'commit' of your website that you can use as a backup to rollback to in case 'something bad happens'

does that answer your question?